# Is WMI a good choice to gather application specific metrics?

Tags: c#, wmi

We have a requirement to gather and analyse several metrics. Some of them quite general - memory and processor usage. Other metrics are application specific. For example we receive price changes for papers, and would like to gather the number of changes per sec, and so on. So it seems reasonable to use WMI for gathering memory and cpu utilization information. What about application specific metrics?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter for collecting memory and cpu utilization. Please visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx for more information. Hope it helps.